# Make Lines of .EPS Graphic Bolder or Thicker

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have an image that looks like a read out of an EKG wavy line.  It's in .EPS format and I have placed it in an Illustrator .AI file I am creating.  I want to make the wavy line thicker looking but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I tried increasing the stroke size from 1 to 2 but then at the start of every path a weird little short burr-like line gets added.

Can someone please let me know if there is a way I can make this line more wide/bold or whatever?

[image: ekg lines]

Comment: please, place a screenshot of the area in question

Comment: You may want to indicate what software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Miter Limit - Adobe Illustrator]

Open the [Stroke Panel](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html) by clicking Stroke and make your way to the limit option.

Alternatively, you can change the corner type in your stroke settings to 'Round'