# Make lines of an EPS file >0.14 points?

Tags: pdf, eps

I am working on publishing a book on Lulu.  One warning it has about my PDF is:

> Images: Your file contains images with line thickness less than 0.14 points. This may be too thin to print. Please review your file.

I have all of the EPS files that go into the book. However, I do not know how they were created, so I cannot edit the originals. Is there a way to edit the EPS directly to make all lines at least 0.14 points?

I see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37393), but they had the original.  I see [this ps_thicken script](https://ferret.pmel.noaa.gov/Ferret/faq/changing-line-thickness-in-postscript-files), but it did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, you can redefine setlinewidth at start of the document so it cant go below 0.14 but its a bit out there kind of solution. Not for people with code allergy.

Comment: I don't have code allergy. How do I do this?

Comment: Just open the file in a text editir an redefine the setlinewidth command. The file is just a programming language snippet. Its pretty well documented online how to redefine builtin commands.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know postscript that well, and this is literally a Q&A site, so I'm hoping someone can answer with working code or a link to some working code.

Comment: Its not entirely within scope of graphic design .se if your into doing this manually in a graphic design application thats fine. But coding is outside of scope.

Comment: Also note: just because you think its a line does not mean it is. It can also be a shape that has been expanded. Then obviously it can not ve widened without manual reworking. Also note that the eps is most likely perfectly passable as original if you have adobe illustrator

Comment: It's impressive if Lulu can hold a .14pt rule.. *most* shops require a .25pt minimum.